# Windows Phone 8 + JQM + Phonegap Issue

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I created an app in phonegap with JQM and I want to test it in WP8. When I test it in WP8 the JQM css doesn't show up at all. The plain text and text boxes only show up. I have added all the files to the project and same issue. I am using Visual Studio Express the links to my files look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="~/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

All these files exist ye the app is not detecting them. I even tried referencing the files with `./` and still nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated as to why this is happening

Comment: Note that Windows phone 8 is not officially supported on Jquery Mobile. See the supported platforms http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call your file like this

```
<script src="/app/www/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the error apparently you cannot use a slash `/` or `\` before the folder names when referencing the folder